# Port 8080 is still closed after adding a TCP custom rule to AWS Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, inbound-security-rule

I have been dealing with a very messy problem which is that I need a new open port in my EC2 instance.

I have a node.js application running in this instance. To make that happen I had to open the port 3000 through adding a new inbound rule in the security groups, which worked perfectly.

Now, I need another port opened so I can send data from an external IP to that port.

I tried opening the port adding a new inbound rule as well, but with not success. The port gets opened but just in the localhost, not in the public or private IP, so I can not telnet to the port.

I have tried adding it to the firewall iptables as well using the Ubuntu shell but I have no success on it.

I would really appreciate any help, any response. Thank you!!

Comment: What IP-address you mentioned for port 8080 in inbound rules?

Comment: I mean it is like 0.0.0.0/0 or custom ip?

Comment: Yes I used 0.0.0.0/0 for port 8080 in inbound rules, because I want that all the traffic can go through the port without limitations.

Comment: Okay. For port 3000 also same ip address right?

Comment: All networking settings are correct?

Comment: yep, they seem to be correct. Port 3000 is working good, I have the same settings for port 8080

Comment: As per question, opened in localhost not in public or private IP - It seems like networking issue. Please check your public subnet has attached internet gateway. Have you tried to open port 3000 with public IP?

Comment: I already found the issue! Thank you very much for your attention and interest! The public subnet was lacking of the internet gateway! Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should do comment to get something clear from you but due to low reputation i can't.
So, just ignore reputation or scoring lets consider learning.
Here are complete tutorial to add new ports in an AWS instance:

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at [EC2 Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/)
2. In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups. Select the security
   group for your instance.
3. Choose Inbound, Edit, Add Rule.
4. For Type, choose choose accordingly.
5. Now it comes "Secure Filed" it decides that which system can access
   this port. So, if you want that only your or some other specific
   systems could access this machine give their IPs e.g. in IPV-6
   format. Or you want this port open publicly just enter 0.0.0.0 as IP
   here.
6. Choose Save.

Please follow this tutorial, I am sure it would work, in your case I think you are missing "Secure Field" thing.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your response, I appreciate it. Yes I am a newbee in this kind of things, by the way why would I need to set the type to SSH?, I need a custom tcp rule to enable a port to receive data, not to use the SSH through another port.

Comment: yes i have updated my answer... check now if it works if doesn't please update me about the issue.